# Having a problem with SQLiteConnection in Xamarin.Forms project in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to get into my SQLite database in Xamarin.Forms project. But I have an issue with connection.Open() method!. When I put the dot after my connection, I cannot see the Open() method in the opening list, and I get an error like that below:

**Error CS1061  'SQLiteConnection' does not contain a definition for 'open' and no accessible extension method 'open' accepting a first argument of type 'SQLiteConnection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

Here is my connection string:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(player))
{
    if (Regex.IsMatch(player, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$"))
    {
         string connectionString = @"Data Source=C:\Users\altan\Desktop\DERSLER MESA CC\deneme\SQLitePhoneGame\phoneGameDB.db;Version=3;UseUTF16Encoding=True;";
         using (SQLiteConnection connection = new SQLiteConnection(connectionString))
         {
         connection.open();
         }
    }
    else
    {
    return;
    }
}
```

Here is the picture of the instance:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYAYP.png)

**PS: Please write down useful information, not what you are assuming! Don't copy and paste anything you saw on the web and other topics! I just need the exact information! I've already checked so many writings. Thank you**

Comment: your app running on a mobile device does not have any idea what "C:\..." is.  Using SQLite with Xamarin apps is pretty well documented: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/data/databases

Comment: Could you please provide full namespace for SQLiteConnection or name for library? Thank you

Comment: @Jason Hey bro, this is not a server-side app now. Just a sample, you know. I don't know how you couldn't figure out "what C:\..." is, the directory of the db on my computer?. I've already checked that site but it doesn't contain the information I'm looking for. I'm looking for a solution to that. Can you make a connection without adding classes or not!!

Comment: *I* know what c:\ means, but I'm a human being.  iOS/Android, however, are mobile operating systems, and neither of them will be able to access c:\ of your desktop.  Please do not be rude to people who are trying to help you.  Step #1 of the docs I linked to explains how to install the correct nuget package, which is the same thing that @ashantiel points out in his answer.

Answer (score 1):

According to your image and what you posted, you are not using the  [Microsoft.Data.SQLite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.data.sqlite.sqliteconnection.open?view=msdata-sqlite-3.1.0) library, but SQLite.Net-PCL. The second doesn't have the Open method at all, connection is opened by using the constructor [github code](https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL/blob/master/src/SQLite.Net/SQLiteConnection.cs#L112).
So answering, your connection is already opened inside {} brackets.